# how do i can extract datas from a docx file?

Tags: python, python-docx

i want to find the number of paragraphs, sentences, words and uniq words in a docx file.
i already installed python-docx and nltk.
i tried many things but nothing worked and i'm out of ideas right now.

this, for exemple, gives me uniq letters instead of unique words :

```
def getText(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        fullText.append(para.text)
    return '\n'.join(fullText)

letexte = getText('demo.docx')
#print(letexte)

dist = FreqDist(letexte)
vocab = dist.keys()

print(len(dist))
print(vocab)
```

anyways... i'm lost.

can you show how you'd do it with a random demo.docx with more than 4 pages ?
thank you

Comment: don't give up, you have nice function `getText()`, you can reach your goal by splitting every time for paragraphs (\n), sentences (by dot) and words using regex I putted in my answer (; |, |\*|\n |\s)

Answer (score 1):

To fing unique words in text you can use simple python script, just pass result of your `getText()` to it and you will get the list with only unique items. From this list you can get the number of unique items applying `len()`

```py
import re

...

def count_unique_words(text_string):
    word_list = re.split('; |, |\*|\n |\s', text_string)
    return list(dict.fromkeys(word_list))

...
print(len(count_unique_words(letexte))
```